# Expand animation with dynamic content height

Tags: html, css, reactjs, animation, css-transitions

I have a problem with animation when I have some dynamic content in my container and it changes when React's state changes. I simulated it here

https://codesandbox.io/embed/romantic-mcnulty-zrtze

I want to trigger expand animation on height when button is clicked. I tried with `min-height` and `max-height` CSS property but it did not work :/ It works when I apply `height` but as I said I cannot set fixed values there.

Regards

Comment: Could you make your code into a SO snippet we can run and also show what you have tried to make it animate e.g. did you set transition and if so on what? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @AHaworth I added codesandbox snippet. SO snippets do not allow to include all dependencies I need

Answer (score 0):

One method is to place an opaque after pseudo element over the new text and then animate its height from 100% to 0.

That way you do not need to know the heights of any of the texts, the pseudo element will pick up the current 100% height.

Here's a snippet in plain JS:

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  container.classList.toggle('long');
  container.innerHTML = container.classList.contains('long') ? 'Some very very very very very very very very very very very very long text which height is unknown' : 'Shorter text but its height is also unknown';
  container.classList.add('reveal');
  container.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
    container.classList.remove('reveal')
  });
});
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  max-width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  --h: 0px;
}

.container::after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--h);
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1;
}

.container.reveal::after {
  animation-name: reveal;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes reveal {
  0% {
    height: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    height: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="App">
  <div class="container">Shorter text but its height is also unknown</div>
  <button>toggle</button></div>
```